# Function calculate between data range only work for first row only

Tags: javascript

the function below is for calculate date range when user select the date...but it only work on first row. for this
I've search some similar problem for this, but seems still cant fix my problem.

```
div class="form-group" >
<label for="newRequestedLeaveDay" style=" font-size: 16px; "> New Reqest  date range :  </label></strong>
<div class="form-inline "> 
            <a style=" font-size: 16px; " >From :</a> <input type="text" onchange="cal1(<?php echo  $row['id'];?>)" id="startDate1" class="startDate1 form-control" name="startDate1" style="margin-left:5px"   /> 

            <a style="margin-left:10px;font-size: 16px;">To :</a> <input type="text" onchange="cal1(<?php echo  $row['id'];?>)" id="endDate1" class="endDate1 form-control" name="endDate"  />

        </div> 
    </div>

<div class="form-group"  >
<label for="noldr" style=" font-size: 16x; ">Number of leave days request :</label></strong><input type="text" class="numdays2" id="numdays2" name="numdays2" readonly /><a style="margin-left:10px;font-size: 16px;">Day</a>  
</div>
```

this is the function call when the user pick a date

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetDay(){
        var dropdate = '';
        var pickdate = '';
        var totalday = '';
            var dropdate = new Date(document.querySelector('.startDate1').value);

            var pickdate = new Date(document.querySelector('.endDate1').value);

            totalday = parseInt((pickdate - dropdate  ) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
            return totalday;
    }

    function cal1(id) {
    if(document.querySelector('.endDate1')){
        document.querySelector('.numdays2').value=GetDay();

    }  
}

</script>
```

I have try getElementByClassName and getElementById , but the onchange still only work on first row only, where what I needed is when the user click different leave request, the function cal1() should be able to work for each of it... Any solution is welcome, thank in advance~

Comment: You have `startDate1` and `endDate1` hard-coded. I don't see how that would ever grab anything else. Not to mention you're passing the `id` into your `cal1` function but never using it.

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector only selects the first match, document.querySelectorAll returns all elements that match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
just have created a dynamic ID for each input. like:  `id="startDate_<?php echo  $row['id'];?>"`,  `id="endDate_<?php echo  $row['id'];?>"` and `id="numdays_<?php echo  $row['id'];?>"`

```
<div class="form-group" >
<label for="newRequestedLeaveDay" style=" font-size: 16px; "> New Reqest  date range :  </label></strong>
<div class="form-inline "> 
            <a style=" font-size: 16px; " >From :</a> <input type="text" onchange="cal1(<?php echo  $row['id'];?>)" id="startDate_<?php echo  $row['id'];?>" class="startDate1 form-control" name="startDate1" style="margin-left:5px"   /> 

            <a style="margin-left:10px;font-size: 16px;">To :</a> <input type="text" onchange="cal1(<?php echo  $row['id'];?>)" id="endDate_<?php echo  $row['id'];?>" class="endDate1 form-control" name="endDate"  />

        </div> 
    </div>

<div class="form-group"  >
<label for="noldr" style=" font-size: 16x; ">Number of leave days request :</label></strong><input type="text" class="numdays2" id="numdays_<?php echo  $row['id'];?>" name="numdays2" readonly /><a style="margin-left:10px;font-size: 16px;">Day</a>  
</div>
```

Script part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetDay( rowId ){
        var dropdate = '';
        var pickdate = '';
        var totalday = '';
            var dropdate = new Date(document.querySelector('#startDate_' + rowId ).value);

            var pickdate = new Date(document.querySelector('#endDate_' + rowId ).value);

            totalday = parseInt((pickdate - dropdate  ) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
            return totalday;
    }

    function cal1( rowId ) {
    if(document.querySelector('#numdays_' + rowId)){
        document.querySelector('#numdays_' + rowId ).value=GetDay( rowId );

    }  
}

</script>
```